# How do i properly store and retrieve an image file path in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I am currently working on a personal stylist app using the codeigniter framework. I would like to display a list of items with their corresponding picture stored in my phpmyadmin database. I have researched about this and i found out that it is best practice to store only the file path of the image instead of storing the image directly in the database. I was just wondering if you guys could help me on how to do this properly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Jairus, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please could you edit your post to include some examples, including code or screenshots, of what you have already tried, what hasn't worked and why if it's clear, and with any error messages if applicable. This will make it much easier for people to understand and answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store relative path to your image. For example if the image is located on `http://www.example.com/uploads/images/picture.jpg`, keep only `/uploads/images/picture.jpg` in database